# Inline SVG <circle> breaks in Firefox when combined with vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a number of inline SVGs in a website I maintain, and they're broken in Firefox. Each  is broken when vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke is applied. They still render, but the last/first points seem to be stretched to the top left point of the page.

e.g. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gY-SO2fbtDRb9AGfeLXvJg3oCKosdrKd/view?usp=sharing
e.g. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lpua-qZyiDlcfFKjLfXWgP8wOa_tZh69/view?usp=sharing

The issue only seems to apply to circles, if I change the tag to an ellipse 
e.g.

```
<ellipse class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill stroke-rounded non-scaling-stroke" cx="69.9" cy="60.1" rx="40.8" ry="40.8"/>
```

the issue goes away, and also if I remove the vector-effect

```
e.g. <circle class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill stroke-rounded" cx="69.9" cy="60.1" r="40.8"/>
```

Running the mouse cursor over the SVG also sometimes fixes the problem.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWQRqg

HTML:

```
  <svg version="1.1" id="parents-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill non-scaling-stroke" d="M116.5,137.6c0,0-17.5-22.6-46.7-22.6c-32,0-52,24.1-58.9,43.9c0,0,25.8,19.8,56.9,19.8c20.2,0,32.4-5,32.4-5"/>
    <path class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill grey-stroke-hover non-scaling-stroke" d="M109.8,166.3c0,0,15.3,13.5,39.5,13.5s39.8-13.5,39.8-13.5S178.9,137,149.5,137S109.8,166.3,109.8,166.3z"/>
    <circle class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill stroke-rounded grey-stroke-hover non-scaling-stroke" cx="149.5" cy="100.4" r="27.1"/>
    <circle class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill stroke-rounded non-scaling-stroke" cx="69.9" cy="60.1" r="40.8"/>
  </svg>
```

CSS:

```
.non-scaling-stroke {
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}

.stroke-2 {
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-miterlimit: 0;
}

.stroke-blue {
    stroke: #009bdf;
}

.no-fill {
    fill: none;
}

.stroke-rounded {
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

Comment: A recent known issue. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1539129 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1538666

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this doesn't happen if you use a path instead of a circle. Also, as it is your code in this moment you have a repeating `id` for the svg elements.

In the next example I'm using a function to create a circle as a path. If you don't want to use javascript you can get the d attribute for the path from the inspector. I hope it helps.

```js
const SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";



function drawCircle(cx, cy, r, parent) {
  let circle_path = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, "path");
  let d = `M${cx + r},${cy} A${r},${r} 0 0 0 ${cx -
    r},${cy}  A${r},${r} 0 0 0 ${cx + r},${cy}z`;
  circle_path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
  parent.appendChild(circle_path);
  return circle_path;
}


let circles = []

circles.push(drawCircle(149.5, 100.4, 27.1, circles1));
circles.push(drawCircle(69.9, 60.1, 40.8, circles1));
circles.push(drawCircle(149.5, 100.4, 27.1, circles2));
circles.push(drawCircle(69.9, 60.1, 40.8, circles2));

circles.map(c=>{
  c.setAttribute("class", "stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill stroke-rounded grey-stroke-hover non-scaling-stroke")
})
```

```css
/* Start the magic css for locking down svg stroke width */

.non-scaling-stroke {
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}

/* End magic */

.blue-fill {
    fill: #009bdf;
}

.stroke-2 {
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-miterlimit: 0;
}
.stroke-blue {
    stroke: #009bdf;
}
.no-fill {
    fill: none;
}
.stroke-rounded {
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px">
  
                        <svg version="1.1" id="parents_icon1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                             viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
                          <path class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill non-scaling-stroke" d="M116.5,137.6c0,0-17.5-22.6-46.7-22.6c-32,0-52,24.1-58.9,43.9c0,0,25.8,19.8,56.9,19.8c20.2,0,32.4-5,32.4-5"/>
                          <path class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill grey-stroke-hover non-scaling-stroke" d="M109.8,166.3c0,0,15.3,13.5,39.5,13.5s39.8-13.5,39.8-13.5S178.9,137,149.5,137S109.8,166.3,109.8,166.3z"/>
                          <!--<circle class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill stroke-rounded grey-stroke-hover non-scaling-stroke" cx="149.5" cy="100.4" r="27.1"/>
                          <circle class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill stroke-rounded non-scaling-stroke" cx="69.9" cy="60.1" r="40.8"/>-->
                        
  
<g id="circles1">  
</g>  
  
  
  
  </svg>
  
</div><div style="width: 200px">
  
                        <svg version="1.1" id="parents_icon2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                             viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
                          <path class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill non-scaling-stroke" d="M116.5,137.6c0,0-17.5-22.6-46.7-22.6c-32,0-52,24.1-58.9,43.9c0,0,25.8,19.8,56.9,19.8c20.2,0,32.4-5,32.4-5"/>
                          <path class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill grey-stroke-hover non-scaling-stroke" d="M109.8,166.3c0,0,15.3,13.5,39.5,13.5s39.8-13.5,39.8-13.5S178.9,137,149.5,137S109.8,166.3,109.8,166.3z"/>
                          <!--<circle class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill stroke-rounded grey-stroke-hover non-scaling-stroke" cx="149.5" cy="100.4" r="27.1"/>
                          <circle class="stroke-blue stroke-2 no-fill stroke-rounded non-scaling-stroke" cx="69.9" cy="60.1" r="40.8"/>-->
                        
  
<g id="circles2">  
</g>    
  </svg>
  
</div>
```