# Firefox 66 rendering issues: SVG circle with vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;

Tags: css, firefox, svg

there are some disturbing issues with rendering a SVG circle with the **Firefox 66.0.2** (see the screenshot). This behavior occurs if the CSS property `vector-effect` is set to `non-scaling-stroke`.

[image]

**example SVG:**

```
<svg height="500" width="500">
    <circle style="vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;" class="x" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" >
</svg>
```

There is also a demo here: 
https://resources.jointjs.com/demos/bpmn

I'd like to find a workaround for temporary fix, as it seems the effect disappears when you move the affected element. However, I couldn't find a way how to "re-render" programmatically. e.g. move, hide-show, set attributes, window resize ... none of these with any effect.

Comment: I've reported a bug as well https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1541845

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488585/inline-svg-circle-breaks-in-firefox-when-combined-with-vector-effect-non-scal) I'm suggesting to use path instead of circle. Please take a look.